# Help about structure of a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

is that a good expression?

As much as you strive you will get, and as much as you lazy you will lose

Comment: You need either a real verb (such as _loaf_) in place of _lazy_ or something like _are_ inserted in front of _lazy_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Lazy* is not a verb that can be used in the way you've used it in your sentence. It's common use is as an adjective. Therefore, the sentence should be tweaked slightly in order for it to be grammatical:

> As much as you strive you will get, and as much as you *are* lazy you will lose.

Alternatively, you could use the word *laze* instead, which is a verb that can be directly substituted without changing anything else:

> As much as you strive you will get, and as much as you *laze* you will lose.

---

Further, the use of punctuation and an additional change would change it stylistically, perhaps giving the sentence more of its intended meaning:

> As much as you strive, so shall you get; as much as you [are lazy / laze], so shall you lose.

This is entirely subjective, and there is nothing ungrammatical about the original version (with the one tweak). All this does is change it to make it sound more like an aphorism—or the idiom [*as you reap, so shall you sow*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+you+sow%2C+so+shall+you+reap) (The Free Dictionary).